# How to extract the X or a tuple value from openCV - findContours where Y=39

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I ran `cv2.findContours` on an image.

The result is 3 contours. This is the output of findContours  -

```
print (cnt)
[array([[[149,   0]],
       [[149,   1]],
       [[148,   2]],
       [[148,   8]],
       [[149,   9]],
       [[149,  11]],
       [[148,  12]],
       [[148,  39]],
       [[213,  39]],
       [[213,  30]],
       [[212,  29]],
       [[213,  28]],
       [[213,  23]],
       [[212,  22]],
       [[212,   3]],
       [[211,   2]],
       [[211,   0]],
       [[161,   0]],
       [[160,   1]],
       [[159,   0]]], dtype=int32), 

array([[[148,   5]],
       [[149,   4]],
       [[150,   5]],
       [[150,   8]],
       [[149,   9]],
       [[148,   8]]], dtype=int32), 
array([[[ 0,  0]],
       [[ 0, 39]]], dtype=int32)]
```

I would like to get the tuples from the first contour [0] where the `y=39`
in this case I would like to get:

```
[[148,  39]],
[[213,  39]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to filter elements in a container.

In your example the data structure is a bit convoluted:

```
selection = [i for i in cnt[0] if i[0][1] == 39]
```

We iterate over `cnt[0]` as it describes the first contour. In the condition, we need an extra index operation (`i[0][1]` instead of `i[1]` due to the extra array wrap) to get to the y value.

We can use this operation instead to simplify the output in one go as well:

```
selection = [i[0] for i in cnt[0] if i[0][1] == 39]
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV contour arrays can be tricky to work with. I usually do this before working with them:

```py
contour = np.array([list(pt[0]) for ctr in contours for pt in ctr])
```

Then you can get your list of points:

```py
pts = contour[np.where(contour[:,1] == 49)]
```

Comment: Great answer! Note that the first line squashes all contours together. Just pointing it out to avoid any confusion.